# Refresh jquery.masonry when deleting an item

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

How do I refresh Masonry when an item is deleted via Ajax? This is the code I'm using to delete the item:

```
if($deletes = $('a[rel=delete]')) {
    $deletes.click(function() {
        if(!window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this picture?'))
            return false;
        $t = $(this);
        $.post(
            $t.attr('href'),
            {},
            function(data) {
                if(data == "success")
                    $t.parents('.deleteable:first').fadeOut();
            }
        );
        return false;           
    });
}
```

The reason I want a refresh is to eliminate the resulting spaces after items are deleted.

Comment: Please consider choosing a correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reorganize all element's after hiding a element using jquery masonry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086900/reorganize-all-elements-after-hiding-a-element-using-jquery-masonry)

Answer (score 5):

Add a callback to your `fadeOut()` to actually call `.remove()` your deleted element once it's faded out, then just call `.masonry()` on the container again.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. Works fine for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I would say just call it again on the selector. It seems to have [a check](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.js) to see if it's been called again.

```
...snip...
  // checks if masonry has been called before on this object
  props.masoned = !!$wall.data('masonry');
...snip...
```

<strike>I also would recommend the `saveOptions` setting, since it seems to support it for re-calls.</strike> Never mind, it seems to do so by default (D'oh!)

Comment: I tried calling it again, using this, but to no effect:

    $('.masonry-wrapper').masonry({ columnWidth: 188, singleMode: true, itemSelector: '.item' });

Answer (score 1):

Call masonry again in fadeout callback. Make this easy on yourself, and do your masonry initialization in a function. Define your options in there so that you don't have to carry the options into your callback scope.

Like so

```
$(function(){

  var $bricks = $('your > elements');

  function BuildWall(){
    $bricks.masonry({your:'options'});
  }

  BuildWall();


 //Your code modified
 if($deletes = $('a[rel=delete]')) {
     $deletes.click(function() {
        if(!window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this picture?'))
           return false;
         var $t = $(this);
         $.post(
            $t.attr('href'),
            {},
            function(data) {
                if(data == "success")
                    $t.parents('.deleteable:first').fadeOut(function(){
                       //This is faster than $(this).remove();
                       $(this).empty().remove();
                       //Reset Masonry
                       BuildWall();
                    });
            }
        );
        return false;           
    });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery masonry itself has a remove method (http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#remove)

you can put this in your fadeOut callback:

```
$("your-container").masonry( 'remove', $(this) ).masonry();
```